# Why is 'select' checkbox in aura lightning:datatable squashed up against next column?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, lightning-datatable, datatable

My aura lightning:datatable 'select' checkbox is squashed up against the next column.  The 'select all' checkbox in the header is not even visible, though it does look to be there, underneath the heading of next column.

[image: Image of table]

Here is the filter and table in my component:

```
    <div class="slds-is-relative">
    <lightning:layout>
        <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="3">
            <lightning:select
                aura:id="select"
                label="Region"
                name="regionFilter"
                value="{!v.filterSelectedValueRegion}"
                onchange="{!c.applyRegionFilter}"
                class="slds-m-bottom_medium"
                >
                <option value="Default">-- Select a Region --</option>
                <option value="All">All</option>
                <aura:iteration var="filterRegionOption" items="{!v.filterOptionsRegion}">
                    <option
                        value="{!filterRegionOption}"
                        text="{!filterRegionOption}"
                        selected="{!filterRegionOption.selected}"
                        />
                </aura:iteration>
            </lightning:select>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>
    <div style="height: 300px" padding="around-small">
        <lightning:datatable
            data="{!v.tableData}"
            columns="{!v.tableColumns}"
            keyField="localId"
            hideCheckboxColumn="false"
            minColumnWidth="50px"
            sortedBy="{! v.sortedBy }"
            sortedDirection="{! v.sortedDirection }"
            onsort="{!c.updateColumnSorting }"
            />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the tableColumns object:

```
[{"label":"Local Id","fieldName":"localId","type":"text","sortable":true},{"label":"Local Quote","fieldName":"localQuote","type":"text","sortable":true},{"label":"Customer","fieldName":"customer","type":"text","sortable":true},{"label":"Contract Period From","fieldName":"contractPeriodFrom","type":"date-local","sortable":true},{"label":"Contract Period To","fieldName":"contractPeriodTo","type":"date-local","sortable":true}]
```

Since the 'select' column is added automatically, and I want it to be there, I don't see anywhere to format it.

I haven't seen any other posts reporting same so guess it's something that I'm (not) doing.

Same in Chrome and Firefox by the way.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: I noticed this in the console:
'The attribute "minColumnWidth" value passed in is incorrect.
            "minColumnWidth" value should be an integer >= 0.'
I added that attribute to all columns, with a value of 50, but it made no difference to the display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed -

[image: screenshot image]

I made no changes at all so I guess it's the Salesforce fairies that I need to thank  :-)